# How to use the indexes in a list within the subprocess module?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

not used python much so still learning. Basically, I have a list of IDs which relate to a specific job. At the moment I just want to be able to pass the first ID in the list (using the a[0]) and print the output of the request to hello.txt. So the entire command itself is going to look like bjobs -l 000001 > hello.txt. Once I've got this done, I can loop through the entire file of IDs to create a separate file for each command output.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import subprocess

a = [ln.rstrip() for ln in open('file1')]

subprocess.call(["bjobs -l ", a[0], "> hello.txt"], shell=True)
```

Any help would be appreciated! If I haven't made myself clear on something then please ask and I'll try and explain.

Comment: What is `bjobs` supposed to do? There's also no need for redirecting output, you can write to a file in Python. Could you also show how `file1` looks like?

Comment: Bjobs is one of our own internal commands, basically it just prints information about a job. File1 is just a list of ids - 

423720
424323
436617
439917
461407
461414
461475
462667
445113
445028
446471
450001
451030
457610
457613
457733
457852
459224

Comment: Is that so, that you're effectively asking how to redirect an output of a subprocess to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want just the first id, do:

```
with open('file1') as f:
    first_id = next(f).strip()
```

The `with` statement will open the file and make sure to close it.

Then you could get the `bjobs` output with something like:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["bjobs", "-l", first_id], shell=True)
```

And write:

```
with open('hello.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(output)
```

I'm suggesting to separate the fetching and writing of the `bjobs` output beacuse you might want to do something on it or maybe you'll write the `bjobs` in Python so... Well this will keep things separated.

If you want to loop on all the ids, you can do it:

```
with open('file1') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        # ...
```

Or with [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#enumerate) if you need the line number:

```
with open('file1') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        line = line.strip()
        # ...
```

I know that I went a little ahead of what you asked, but it seems like you're starting to build something, so I thought it might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

How about this file, named `spam.py`:

```
with open('file1') as f:
  for line in f:
    subprocess.call([ 'bjobs', '-l', line.rstrip() ])
```

Then call it using `python spam.py > hello.txt`.